# What kind of syntax of Scala syntax is this?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I know the basic syntax of Scala, but in the following code, I don't understand what the `describe` and `it` constructs are doing. Are they some kind of anonymous functions or what?

```
class SentimentAnalyzerSpec extends FunSpec with Matchers {

  describe("sentiment analyzer") {

    it("should return POSITIVE when input has positive emotion") {
      val input = "Scala is a great general purpose language."
      val sentiment = SentimentAnalyzer.mainSentiment(input)
      sentiment should be(Sentiment.POSITIVE)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's a testing DSL. Check out http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_fun_spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just methods and variables inherited from the mixin traits. You can do a similar thing yourself:

```
trait MyDsl {
  def bar(n: Int) = 123
  def foo(s: String)(d: String) = 234
}
```

So if you mix it in another class, you can write

```
class MyClass1 extends MyDsl {
  bar(foo("hello")("hi"))
}
```

(note that `foo` is a multi parameter list function, which does not exist in Java)

Because Scala lets you omit parentheses via *infix notation*, `(` might be omitted and replaced with `{` to group the parameter-expression. So it becomes:

```
class MyClass1 extends MyDsl {
  bar {
    foo("hello") {
      "hi"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, all of these definitions are actually happening inside the primary constructor of `MyClass1`

Comment: "Scala lets you specify parameters to methods using `{` in addition to the traditional `(`": That's not perfectly accurate - you can't just replace `(` with `{` when calling methods. Here, the parenthesis are simply _omitted_ (which can be done for arity-one methods, i.e. the infix notation), and the curly braces here are just block delimiters, just like when you write something like `val x = { print("Hi"); 1 }`, unrelated to the method call.

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic DSL (Domain Specific Language) provided by `ScalaTest`, via the `FunSuite`.

`describe` is a method, accepting a `String` and a by name value which returns `Unit` via a multiple argument list:

```
protected def describe(description: String)(fun: => Unit) {
    registerNestedBranch(description, None, fun, "describeCannotAppearInsideAnIt", sourceFileName, "describe", 4, -2, None)
}
```

It simply uses infix notation, that is why it looks semi "magical".

`it` is a value which holds a class called `ItWord`. it has an `apply` method which simply registers the method you supply as a test:

```
/**
* Supports test (and shared test) registration in <code>FunSpec</code>s.
* This field supports syntax such as the following:
* it("should be empty")
* it should behave like nonFullStack(stackWithOneItem)
*/
protected val it = new ItWord

protected class ItWord {
  def apply(specText: String, testTags: Tag*)(testFun: => Unit) {
    engine.registerTest(specText, Transformer(testFun _), "itCannotAppearInsideAnotherItOrThey", sourceFileName, "apply", 3, -2, None, None, None, testTags: _*)
  }
}
```

Comment: The String isn't passed by name, the `Unit` is (and it's not technically a function).

Comment: @sepp2k Not sure why I said the `String` was by name. Fixed.